# Is there a better way to code a ajax call in fancybox2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

If you look at the code I use 2 fancybox calls. The reason I do this is because I only want a part of the page I get using ajax. That part is within ajaxEventContent class.

I would like to do this in one call if possible. Thank you.

```
$("#events .popUp").live('click' ,function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $.fancybox({

        'content' : '<div style="text-align:center"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>',
        'width'     : 680,
        'minWidth' : 680,
        'height'    : 'auto',
        'autoHeight' : true,
        'beforeLoad' : function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                success: function( data ) {
                    //get content with ajax
                    content = $(data).find('.ajaxEventContent');
                    $.fancybox({

                        'content': content,
                        'width': 680,
                        'height': 'auto'

                    });

                }
            });
         }
    });

});
```

Comment: I know. It was a copy paste from an old project that uses fancybox1 and an older jquery. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Actually this seems to work. Except you don't get the loading.gif part which is fine

```
$("#events .modal").on('click' ,function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function( data ) {
            //get content with ajax
            content = $(data).find('.ajaxEventContent');
            $.fancybox({

                content : content,
                width       : 680,
                helpers:  {
                    overlay : {
                        locked : false
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });

});
```